# Html Insert in Database JSON Response with %20

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, escaping

I am working on a project where i have to store html content in the database. and get the json response from the server.

MY SETTINGS IN MY CODE.

IN HTML

```
[<DIV contenteditbale='true' id='content' ></div>]
```

IN JAVASCRIPT

```
escape($('#content').html())
```

using jquery `$.Post`

IN C# ASP.NET.

```
validateRequest="false"
```

Everything is working fine. but when i see my response in the fiddler html content comes with the many %20. (i found it in the fiddler), before writing on the page i unescape the response to get the proper html result. there is no problem with %20 but it seems that its overhead and it makes content length and size larger. Is my code is fine for that case? 
or what would be the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Using escape() causes the space to be converted in %20 !!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `escape`. `$.post` automatically encodes parameters, so you're encoding them twice. ASP.NET decodes them once, so you're left with the extra encoding.

Comment: Yes may be escaping or not its not a problem. my problem is that i received my json response something like that 

"Content":"%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A//isotope.metafizzy.co/%22%3Ehttp%3A//isotope.metafizzy.co/%3C/a%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cb%3EMasonry%20Jquery%20guide%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%228123019%22%3Ehttp%3A//www.creativebloq.com/css3/get-started-jquery-masonry-"}

Comment: i resolved it by unescape, i dont know its fine or not i am confused. code is work fine i just asking for the best.